# StartupUri null when using custom Application class in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a very basic custom App.xaml file, with it's build action set to `Page`, which looks like this:

```
<root:TestApp x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns:root="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" />
```

The entry point (inside App.xaml.cs) to the application looks like this:

```
 public partial class App : TestApp
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var app = new App();
            app.InitializeComponent();
            app.Run();
        }
    }
```

Putting a breakpoint on `app.Run()` shows that StartupUri is null, which makes me think the call to `app.InitializeComponent()` is failing (specifically `System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);`)

Can anyone offer any ideas? No exceptions are thrown, it just seems to not load any values from my xaml file.

Comment: Shouldn't the Build Action be `ApplicationDefinition`?

Comment: @Clemens By default it is, but if you want to write you're own `Main()` implementation `Page` is the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated `InitializeComponent()` method of the App class does something completely different when the Build Action is `Page` instead of `ApplicationDefinition`.

Especially it misses the line

```
this.StartupUri = new System.Uri("MainWindow.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
```

---

Instead of (or in addition to) calling `InitializeComponent()`, you may directly set the `StartupUri`:

```
public partial class App : TestApp
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        var app = new App();
        app.InitializeComponent(); // optional?
        app.StartupUri = new Uri("MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        app.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Clemens. Just for reference, the  `InitializeComponent()` is indeed optional, but without it, content inside `<Application.Resources />` will not be initialised.